# Why do more levels not show in the logistic regression summary in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic

So I have a df with 6 variables and 334 obs, and one of the variables (doctor) consists of 11 levels. Doctor 1,2,3, etc.. till 11. When I do this:

```
fit <- lm(surgery~ fracture + age + diagnosis + doctor, data=df)
summary(fit)
```

the result is as follows:

```
lm(formula surgery~ fracture + time+ diagnosis + doctor +age , data=df)
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.9580 -0.3892  0.0311  0.3669  0.8584 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.227e-01  1.566e-01   0.783   0.4342    
fracture    -2.992e-01  6.811e-02  -4.393 1.59e-05 *** 
waittime    -4.420e-05  2.362e-05  -1.872   0.0623 .  
diagnosisLO2 1.548e-01  1.576e-01   0.982   0.3267    
diagnosisLO3 7.911e-01  1.370e-01   5.776 2.03e-08 ***
diagnosisLO5 3.914e-01  1.261e-01   3.105   0.0021 ** 
diagnosisLO6 1.345e-01  1.929e-01   0.697   0.4864    
doctor       3.077e-02  7.440e-03   4.137 4.67e-05 ***
age         -3.037e-03  1.786e-03  -1.700   0.0902 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4281 on 279 degrees of freedom
  (46 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2758,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.255 
F-statistic: 13.28 on 8 and 279 DF,  p-value: 2.971e-16
```

Why are the doctor levels not showing? What am i doing wrong? I also tried coding it with dummy codes as follows:

```
install.packages("fastDummies")
library(fastDummies)
dfdummy <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "doctor")
```

but to no avail. Any clues?

Comment: It **really** helps to reduce your situation to a minimal reproducible example. For instance, this code produces the same problem: `summary(lm(surgery ~ doctor, data.frame(surgery=rnorm(3), doctor=1:3)))`  Because there are only three observations in this dataset you should have no trouble identifying and fixing the problem.

Comment: The most likely reason is that `doctor` is coded as numeric, not a factor. So try: `lm(surgery~ fracture + age + diagnosis + as.factor(doctor), data=df)`

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

**TL:DR :** Code your variable as a factor.

**The long version:**

While this question appears to be about software, there is a fundamental statistical issue at the heart of it, which I find is often not well understood bvy students.

It is always good to remember what a regression coefficient for a variable means:

- it is the association of a 1 unit change in that variable, with a change in the outcome / response (leaving any other variables in the model unchanged)

So, consider for a moment this very simple dataset, consisting of just one variable `doc` taking the numeric values 1, 2 and 3:

```
(dt <- data.frame( doc = rep(1:3, 2)))
##  doc
##   1
##   2
##   3
##   1
##   2
##   3
```

When we use this in a regression model, R will create a *model matrix*, typically called $X$ which is used to fit the model:

$$ Y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

where $Y$ is the outcome, $\beta$ is the regression coeffcients and $\epsilon$ is the error. In the above case, $X$ will be:

```
 (X <- model.matrix(~ doc, dt))
  (Intercept) doc
           1   1
           1   2
           1   3
           1   1
           1   2
           1   3
```

So we have a column of 1s for the intercept (because it is constant for every observation) and an exact copy of our `doc` variable. So, the model would estimate two coefficients, an intercept and an estimate for `doc`. Suppose that these were 5 and 2 respectively, that is $\beta = (5 \: \: \: \: 2)$.  It is then very easy to see that $X\beta$ will be:

$$ \begin{align}
           1\times 5 \: \:+ \: \:  1\times 2  \: \:=& 7 \\
           1\times5 \: \:+ \: \:  2\times2  \: \:=& 9  \\
           1\times5 \: \:+ \: \:  3\times2  \: \:=& 11 \\
           1\times5 \: \: +\: \:   1\times2 \: \: =& 7 \\
           1\times5 \: \:+ \: \:  2\times2 \: \: =& 9 \\
           1\times5 \: \:+ \: \:  3\times2 \: \: =& 11
\end{align}
$$

Note that the interpretation of the regression coefficients is:

- the intercept is the expected value of the outcome when `doc` is zero: that is: $1 \times 5 + 1\times 0  = 5$
- the estimate for `doc` is the change in the outcome that is associated with a 1 unit change in `doc` - which can be seen from inspection is 2.

Now, when `doc` is categorical a little more work is needed. This is usuallly accomplished by using dummy variables and some contrast coding framework, which is often *treatment constrasts*. Let us repeat the above, but this time using treatment contrasts for categorical `doc` with levels "A", "B" and "C":

```
(dt.f <- data.frame( doc = LETTERS[rep(1:3, 2)]))
##  doc
##   A
##   B
##   C
##   A
##   B
##   C
 (X <- model.matrix(~ doc, dt.f))
##  (Intercept) docB docC
##           1    0    0
##           1    1    0
##           1    0    1
##           1    0    0
##           1    1    0
##           1    0    1
```

What is hapenning here ? This indicates that the model will produce 3 estimates, one for the intercept, one for `docB` and one for `docC`. Note that the value in the model matrix for the relevant level of `doc` is 1 when it corresponds to that level, and zero otherwise. Thus, `docA` is  implicitly included in the intercept and we refer to `A` as the *reference level* for `doc`

So, similar to before, let's suppose that the coefficient estimages are 5, 3 and 2 so that $\beta = (5 \: \: \: \: 3\: \: \: \: 2)$. Then $X\beta$ will be:

$$ \begin{align}
           1\times 5  \: \: +  0\times 3 \; \;+ 0 \times 2 =& 5 \\
           1\times5 \; \;+   1\times 3  \; \;+ 0 \times 2 =& 8 \\
           1\times5 \; \;+   0\times 3  \; \;+ 1 \times 2 =& 7 \\
           1\times5 \; \;+   0\times 3  \; \;+ 0 \times 2 =& 5 \\
           1\times5 \; \;+   1\times 3  \; \;+ 0 \times 2 =& 8 \\
           1\times5 \; \;+   0\times 3  \; \;+ 1 \times 2 =& 7 
\end{align}$$

As for interpretation:

- the intercept is the expected value of the response when all the variables are zero, which implicitly means when `doc` is at it's reference level of `A`
- As before, the estimates for `docB` and `docC` are the associated change in the outcome for a 1 unit change in the variable, so for `docB` this is the difference in the outcome between `docB` and `docA`, and for `docC` this is the difference in the outcome between `docC` and `docA`. That is `docB` is associated with reponse that is 3 units greater than `docA`, and `docC` is associated with reponse that is 2 units greater than `docA`. We can then infer that docB is associated with reponse that is 1 unit greater than `docC`. However note that with more levels

This was a very long way of explaining that to fix your problem, you should encode your `doctor` variable as categorical.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you doctor variable is a factor by using Class function. There is no need for you to create a dummy variable. R when it see a factor variable it will create a dummy variable on its own. It will choose one of the levels as a reference to give you estimates.